# Converting quaternions to Euler angles. Problems with the range of Y angle

Tags: c++, math, 3d, irrlicht, ode-library

I'm trying to write a 3d simulation in C++ using Irrlicht as graphic engine and ODE for physics. Then I'm using a function to convert ODE quaternions to Irrlicht Euler angles. In order to do this, I'm using this code.

```
void QuaternionToEuler(const dQuaternion quaternion, vector3df &euler)
{
    dReal w,x,y,z;

    w = quaternion[0];
    x = quaternion[1];
    y = quaternion[2];
    z = quaternion[3];

    double sqw = w*w;    
    double sqx = x*x;    
    double sqy = y*y;    
    double sqz = z*z; 

    euler.Z = (irr::f32) (atan2(2.0 * (x*y + z*w),(sqx - sqy - sqz + sqw)) * (180.0f/irr::core::PI));
    euler.X = (irr::f32) (atan2(2.0 * (y*z + x*w),(-sqx - sqy + sqz + sqw)) * (180.0f/irr::core::PI));          
    euler.Y = (irr::f32) (asin(-2.0 * (x*z - y*w)) * (180.0f/irr::core::PI));

}
```

It works fine for drawing in the correct position and rotation but the problems come with the `asin` instruction. It only return values in the range of `0..90` - `0..-90` and I need to get a range from `0..360` degrees. At least I need to get a rotation in the range of `0..360` when I call `node->getRotation().Y`.

Comment: On `[0°,360°]`, `sin` takes every value twice, so there is no sensible way for `asin` (the inverse sine function) to return values between 0° and 360°.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Euler angles (of any type) have a singularity. In the case of those particular Euler angles that you are using (which look like Tait-Bryan angles, or some variation thereof), the singularity is at plus-minus 90 degrees of pitch (Y). This is an inherent limitation with Euler angles and one of the prime reasons why they are rarely used in any serious context (except in aircraft dynamics because all aircraft have a very limited ability to pitch w.r.t. their velocity vector (which might not be horizontal), so they rarely come anywhere near that singularity).

This also means that your calculation is actually just one of two equivalent solutions. For a given quaternion, there are two solutions for Euler angles that represent that same rotation, one on one side of the singularity and another that mirrors the first. Since both solutions are equivalent, you just pick the one on the easiest side, i.e., where the pitch is between -90 and 90 degrees.

Also, you code needs to deal with approaching the singularity in order to avoid getting NaN. In other words, you must check if you are getting close (with a small tolerance) to the singular points (-90 and 90 degrees on pitch), and if so, use an alternate formula (which can only compute one angle that best approximates the rotation).

If there is any way for you to avoid using Euler angles altogether, I highly suggest that you do that, pretty much any representation of rotations is preferable to Euler angles. Irrlicht uses matrices natively and also supports setting/getting rotations via an [axis-angle representation](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1core_1_1_c_matrix4.html#a2fad61540e78fc7dafe7f6270b0558ac), this is much nicer to work with (and much easier to obtain from a quaternion, and doesn't have singularities).

Answer (score 1):

Think about the earth's globe. Each point on it can be defined only usin latitude(in the range `[-90, 90]`) and longitude(in the range `[-180, 180]`). So each point on a sphere may be specified by using these angles. Now a point on a sphere specifies a vector and all points on a sphere specify all possible vectors. So just like pointed out in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles), the formula you use will generate all possible directions.

Hope this helps.